# How to have a Navigation link open a different view?

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I keep trying to have the navigation links in the surveys list in contentView to open detailView when selected. I keep getting errors Missing argument for parameter 'newsurvey' in call Insert 'newsurvey: <#Survey#>'

Here's the home view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var surveys: [Survey] = []
    @State var isPresented = false
    @State var selectedTab: Int = 0
    @State private var path = [String]()
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack{
                NavigationView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("")
                            .frame(height: 0)
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                        //reduces navbartitle height
                            .toolbar {
                                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                                    Image("RR_Logo_Primary_Full_Color")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 275.0, height: 55.0)
                                        
                                }
                            }
                          
                    
                    List(surveys) { survey in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(newsurvey: survey)) //must be within navigationview
                        {
                            HStack{
                                ZStack {
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .frame(width: 400, height: 100.0)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        
                                        .cornerRadius(4)
                                        
                                    HStack (alignment: .top) {
                                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                            Text(survey.customerName)
                                                .offset(x: -60, y: -2)
                                                .font(.custom("Roboto-Light", size: 24))
                                            
                                            Text(survey.lineName)
                                                .offset(x: -60, y: -5)
                                                .font(.custom("Roboto-Light", size: 18))
                                            
                                            Text("# of conveyors")
                                                .offset(x: -60)
                                        }
                                        VStack {
                                            Text(dateFormatter.string(from: survey.date))
                                                .font(.custom("Roboto-Light", size: 18))
                                                .offset(x: 60)
                                        }
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    }
                }
                .environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 1)
                CustomTabBar(surveys: $surveys, isPresented: $isPresented)
                    .frame(height: 60, alignment: .bottom)
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I tried the following code below but I keep getting not in scope error.

```
    @State var newsurvey: Survey
    @State var surveys: [Survey] = []
    @State private var conveyorName = ""
    @State private var masterTag = ""
    @State private var showAddConveyorSheet = false
    @State private var conveyors: [Conveyor] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(conveyors, id: \.name) { conveyor in
                        NavigationLink(destination: ConveyorTrack(conveyor: conveyor)) {
                            Text(conveyor.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.showAddConveyorSheet = true
                }) {
                    Text("Add Conveyor")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Conveyors", displayMode: .inline)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showAddConveyorSheet) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Conveyor Name", text: $conveyorName)
                        TextField("Master Tag", text: $masterTag)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                // open camera and scan text here
                            }
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.conveyors.append(Conveyor(id: self.conveyorName, name: self.conveyorName, masterTag: self.masterTag))
                        
                        self.conveyorName = ""
                        self.masterTag = ""
                        self.showAddConveyorSheet = false
                    }) {
                        Text("Save")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       DetailView(newsurvey: survey)
    }
}
```

Comment: Most apps only need 1 navigation view at the very top, you have many and are not at the very top.

Comment: Since NavigationView has been deprecated, have you considered migrating to NavigationStack? Help others help you by providing a minimal but complete code example. The code as provided doesn't recreate the error.

Comment: So I removed the navigation view, and it works, however, now I have the customTabBar in the when I select the navigation link to the detailView. Is there a way to get rid of the custom tab bar when navigating to other views?